# Determine Lat/Long of "off-center" point of a top-down image

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthophoto, photogrammetry

I am a computer science student with a top down photo taken by a drone. This drone has relatively low to zero gimble yaw/pitch (0-10deg), isn't very high up (~15m) in flat lands pretty close to sea level. The drone has taken a picture of a group of objects, and their dimensions are known, including height. I have a solid amount of gimble  metadata, including the center point lat/long of the drone. I have the (x,y) coords of the other objects in the image. But I need to generate a lat/long for them. I wouldn't say survey level accuracy is my utmost concern at the moment.

Digging through this GIS exchange, I have looked at several different methods including monoplotting, orthorectification, photogrammetry, UTM conversion, geodesy, and some others. I'm also seeing slight differences in reasons for taking some of the approaches, and I don't quite fully understand which would be the best for my problem.

I've pasted an example photo below. The red-cross is the center point, a known lat/log and (x,y) value. Each green circle is an object of the same dimension (known values), and the distance away from the center point is also known. Any tips for starting out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible approaches.

1. Use some [Structure From Motion](https://www.opendronemap.org/webodm/) software, and a group of overlapping images to generate an orthomosaic of your area of interest.  Export that orthomosaic to UTM coordinates, bring the orthomosaic into some GIS software and id the coordinates of your points of interest.
2. If your drone is a commercially available drone (or you know the sensor size in addition to the information available to you in the EXIF data) you can use a [ground sampling distance calculator](https://www.propelleraero.com/gsd-calculator/) to return the expected spatial resolution of your image.  Convert your center lat/longs to UTM meters. The count the pixels (in both x and y) to your points of interest.  Calculate the coordinates of your points of interest based on the pixel counts.
3. You state that you know the coordinates of the red cross and the distance to the points of interest. It also looks like you know the directions to those points of interest. Convert the red cross location to UTM meters.  Assume the red cross coordinates are (0,0).  Use the distances and directions to calculate the polar coordinates of your points of interest. Convert those point of interest polar coordinates back to Cartesian coordinates.  Add or subtract the actual red cross UTM coordinates to you point of interest coordinates to get the  UTM coordinates of your areas of interest.